# cgridview ajax pagination and javascript for checkbox

Tags: ajax, yii

I have one CSS file and two javacript files for checkboxs look (in CGridView), and when I change the page using ajax pagination on cgridview I get default look of checkboxes. How do I pass these things?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rerun your checkbox javascript code on [afterAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail).